# How can I select a dropdown option with vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown, html-select

I'm trying to select an option in a dropdown menu using JavaScript, but I cannot seem to find any way to do it. The goal is to have a specific input field appear when a specific option is selected. Conversely, if nothing is selected, then the input fields are hidden.

Currently, when you select an option, nothing happens. I am using vanilla JavaScript for this, no jQuery.

```js
const variableFee = document.getElementById('variableFee').value = "Variable";
const fixedFee = document.getElementById('fixedFee').value = "Fixed";
const feeChoice = document.getElementById('feeChoice');


// ---------------- Fixed VS Variable Fee Calculation ---------------- //
// ------------------------------------------------------------------- //
function transactionFeeInput() {
    if (feeChoice == variableFee) {
        variableFee.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

```css
#variableFeeInput, #fixedFeeInput {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="transactionFeeSection">
                        <h3>What is the transaction fee?</h3>
                        <label for="feeChoice"></label>
                        <select name="feeChoice" id="feeChoice">
                            <option id="blankOption" selected="true" disabled="disabled">-- Select an Option --</option>
                            <option id="variableFee" value="variable">Variable</option>
                            <option id="fixedFee" value="fixed">Fixed</option>
                        </select>
                        <input id="variableFeeInput" type="number" placeholder="Enter Percentage - 0%">
                        <input id="fixedFeeInput" type="number" placeholder="Enter Amount - $0.00">
                    </div>
```

I'm not seeing any console errors, so I'm not sure what to fix?

Answer (score 0):

The fields that should appear have the ids `variableFeeInput` and `fixedFeeInput`, but you’re selecting `variableFee` and `fixedFee` (the options) and assigning values to them, then putting those values instead of the elements themselves in the variables.

Incorrect:

```
const variableFee = document.getElementById('variableFee').value = "Variable";
```

Correct:

```
const variableFee = document.getElementById('variableFeeInput');
```

Then, when trying to check which option is selected, you need to compare the dropdown’s `value` property to the option value you’ve set in the HTML.

Incorrect:

```
if (feeChoice == variableFee) {
```

Correct:

```
if (feeChoice.value === 'variable') {
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const variableFee = document.getElementById('variableFeeInput');
const fixedFee = document.getElementById('fixedFeeInput');
const feeChoice = document.getElementById('feeChoice');


// ---------------- Fixed VS Variable Fee Calculation ---------------- //
// ------------------------------------------------------------------- //
function transactionFeeInput() {
  
  
 
     
    if (feeChoice.value == 'variable') {
    
   
        variableFee.style.display = "inline-block";
        fixedFee.style.display = "none";
    }else{
    
        fixedFee.style.display = "inline-block";
        variableFee.style.display = "none";
    
}}
```

```css
#variableFeeInput, #fixedFeeInput {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="transactionFeeSection">
                        <h3>What is the transaction fee?</h3>
                        <label for="feeChoice"></label>
                        <select name="feeChoice" id="feeChoice" onchange="transactionFeeInput()">
                            <option id="blankOption" selected="true" disabled="disabled">-- Select an Option --</option>
                            <option id="variableFee" value="variable">Variable</option>
                            <option id="fixedFee" value="fixed">Fixed</option>
                        </select>
                        <input id="variableFeeInput" type="number" placeholder="Enter Percentage - 0%">
                        <input id="fixedFeeInput" type="number" placeholder="Enter Amount - $0.00">
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close ;), but as others have pointed out there are some issues with your javascript ids and references (HTML and CSS are fine). You don't need the constant declarations either—HTML elements are already in the Document Object Model (DOM) and can be referenced by id:

```
// ---------------- Fixed VS Variable Fee Calculation ---------------- //
// ------------------------------------------------------------------- //
function transactionFeeInput() {
    if (feeChoice.value === "variable") { // check for selected value
        variableFeeInput.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hectorjrivas/3xawqp6L/10/

Answer (score -1):

I believe the only thing you're doing wrong is writing "Variable" and "Fixed" with capital letters, while the values you ahve in your options are "variable" and "fixed".

EDIT: Or, you are setting the value using the options! Try dooing
`document.querySelector('#feeChoice').value = "fixed"`

Answer (score -3):

```
    const variableFee = document.getElementById('variableFee').value = "Variable";
    const fixedFee = document.getElementById('fixedFee').value = "Fixed";
    const feeChoice = document.getElementById('feeChoice');


    // ---------------- Fixed VS Variable Fee Calculation ---------------- //
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    function transactionFeeInput() {
//you need to get the value of feeChoice
        if (feeChoice.value  == variableFee) {
            variableFee.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
    #variableFeeInput, #fixedFeeInput {
        display: none;
    }
    <div id="transactionFeeSection">
                            <h3>What is the transaction fee?</h3>
                            <label for="feeChoice"></label>
                            <select name="feeChoice" id="feeChoice">
<!-- Default value should be "" -->
                                <option id="blankOption" value="" selected="true" disabled="disabled">-- Select an Option --</option>
                                <option id="variableFee" value="variable">Variable</option>
                                <option id="fixedFee" value="fixed">Fixed</option>
                            </select>
                            <input id="variableFeeInput" type="number" placeholder="Enter Percentage - 0%">
                            <input id="fixedFeeInput" type="number" placeholder="Enter Amount - $0.00">
                        </div>
```